# Background-image: url and gradient

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, gradient

I've got some CSS that works in Chrome and Safari. Only problem is it doesn't work in Internet Explorer and Firefox. I think I'm missing something here. The code that I'm using is the following CSS:

```
.bg-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 830px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(223,237,202,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(105,210,190,0.9))), url('../img/profileheader.jpg');
    background-image: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(223,237,202,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(105,210,190,0.9))), url('../img/profileheader.jpg');
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(223,237,202,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(105,210,190,0.9))), url('../img/profileheader.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Do I need -ms-gradient? I read somewhere that wasn't necessary. Thanks in advance tho!

Answer (score 0):

ColorZilla will Absolutely solve this problem for you. I can't tell you how many times this utility has saved my buttocks! :)

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Yea I already saw that one. Only problem is, you cant add an background url to that. And the gradient itself isn't causing problems. It's the combination between a gradient and the url.

Comment: I think you can do what you want by adding backgroundimage:  url('../img/profileheader.jpg') before the gradient lines

Comment: Then again, maybe I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Is the Url pointing to a backup image or is that image supposed to be displayed on top of the gradient?

Comment: Christopher White, indeed the image should be supposed to be displayed underneath the gradient. That's why the opacity of the gradient is set to 0.9. Example is right over here: http://www.woutervdkamp.nl/portfoliov2

Comment: ahh, in this case I would use a containing div with the image as a background, for compatibility's sake

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'background-image' try 'background' only. Background works with colors and images.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the solution myself. Thanks for giving some options tho! Solution:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(223,237,202,0.9)), to(rgba(105,210,190,0.9))), url(''); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(223,237,202,0.9), rgba(105,210,190,0.9)), url(''); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(223,237,202,0.9), rgba(105,210,190,0.9)), url(''); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(223,237,202,0.9), rgba(105,210,190,0.9)), url(''); /* IE10 */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(223,237,202,0.9), rgba(105,210,190,0.9)), url(''); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(223,237,202,0.9), rgba(105,210,190,0.9)), url(''); /* W3C */
```

At least works in firefox, not sure in internet explorer, I'm working on a mac.